# Getting better resolution using X on OpenBSD w/VMWare Fusion

Tags: xorg, openbsd, vmware

Just setup an OpenBSD 4.8 VM for VMWare Fusion. Can't seem to force X to any decent resolution. I attempted to try and use the VMWare tools for FreeBSD, but no dice.

Any suggestions to try and get at least 1280x1024?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you can't use binaries or drivers for FreeBSD on OpenBSD. OpenBSD, NetBSD and FreeBSD are very different OS.

Respect to your problem with the resolution. You need configure Xorg, probably the problem is that you are using the driver "vesa" and no the driver "vmware".

Other suggestion: update to [5.1](http://openbsd.org/51.html). OpenBSD enhances the hardware support with each new release.

Answer (score 2):

Running `xrandr` in your VM should list your "monitor" and it's minimum/maximum size. If those numbers are wrong (based on what you've laid out by VMware), then X is misconfigured or can't seem to detect proper monitor size (without more info we can't say)

If they are right, then you simply haven't configured X to use the full screen space (which is odd because it usually defaults to the best resolution). You should be able to change that in `xorg.conf`, however a BSD implementation might be different from a Linux one (which is what I'm used to)

More information would definitely help in diagnosing the issue, bit the above should lead you on the right path.

Comment: _You should be able to change that in xorg.conf, however a BSD implementation might be different from a Linux one (which is what I'm used to)_. FYI, the implementation is different but the xorg.conf file is 99% the same :)